# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861

Tags: sql, oracle, date, nls

I have given query for which i am getting error as `SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string 01861`. `ORD_DEL_DATE` is date data type and the value is stored `27-SEP-2017 12-00-00` in this column. Its not possible for me to change the `NLS` setting so is it possible if i can change in the query and make it run.

```
SELECT * from Report_Result
    WHERE ORD_DEL_DT >= TO_CHAR( TRUNC ( SYSDATE , 'IW' ) - 7 , 'YYYYMMDD' )
and ORD_DEL_DT <  TO_CHAR ( TRUNC ( SYSDATE , 'IW' ), 'YYYYMMDD' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right-hand side returns something like '20171009', an eight-digit VARCHAR2 string. Since the left-hand side is a date, Oracle tries to convert this string to a date, using the NLS date parameter, and it fails because the string doesn't match the NLS setting.

Why are you working with strings at all? If `ORD_DEL_DT` is a date, compare it to `trunc(sysdate, 'iw') - 7` and `trunc(sysdate, 'iw')`.